# Parsleyjs removing constraint and re-evaluating field?

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I have a very large form with various sections that can be enabled and disabled by the user.  Within those sections I have fields with parsley data attributes for validation.  I would like to remove the validation attributes for those fields when the section is disabled, and add them back when the section is enabled.  I've tried doing this using the addConstraint and removeConstraint javascript as shown below:

```
    function ToggleVehicleInfo(toggleState) {
        if (toggleState) {
            $("#tbVehicleLicenseNumber").parsley('removeConstraint', 'required');
        } else {
            $("#tbVehicleLicenseNumber").parsley('addConstraint', { required: true });
        }
    }
```

But this just seems to remove the parsley-error class, but not the error text.  Sometimes it doesn't have any effect on the field at all. See below - top is when the field has been tabbed through, bottom is after I've tried to remove the required constraint:

[image]

So my question is, what am I doing wrong?  Also, is there a better way of handling this?  Any complete examples of how this is done?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding and removing constraints, have you tried using a listener to only process the relevant sections of the form?

Here is one I used to ignore hidden fields during validation (uses jquery):

```
    listeners: {
        onFieldValidate: function ( elem, ParsleyField ) {
            // if field is not visible, do not apply Parsley validation!
            if ( !$( elem ).is( ':visible' ) ) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
```

You could probably set some indicator as to which section of the form you are validating, and if the current field is not in that section, skip it by returning false.